# How to use java to connect to local Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

Is it need install anything? And if need , I want to get a full step to follow.
And a simple connection coding.
Thank you

Comment: This is a homework.. Give me the code format..

Comment: I think it's not. It's more like someone is lazy to google.

Comment: Full steps:

Step 1: Google
Step 2: Code
Step 3: Ask for help if needed

Comment: Sucks when you google it and this is the first thing you find...

Answer (score 11):

See [this tutorial](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090401&page=1).

In short:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName", "root", "secret");
```

You can also use `DriverManager.registerDriver(..)` instead of the `Class.forName(..)`.

Of course you will need to download the `mysql-connection-x.jar` (the [jdbc driver](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)) and put it on your classpath.

Comment: +1. I would just add "make sure MySQL's JDBC driver is in your classpath".

Comment: And you need to download the driver for your database, as stated in the tutorial. MySQL also has examples on their dev. site.

Comment: Configuring MySQL Database must be need?

Comment: well, yes, you must create a database using  `CREATE DATABASE`  (see the manual for more details)

Comment: It appears that the link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to download MySql Driver, and add it into your java library or class path. Then try this,

```
 try
   {
    Class.forName("com.MySql.jdbc.Driver");
    String Url = "jdbc:MySql://localhost:3306/databaseName";
    connection=DriverManager.getConnection(Url);
    String query="Select * from TableName";
    resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query); 
    }catch(Exception ex){
   System.out.println("Connection Error");
  }
```

Comment: The classname and URL in this example are invalid.

Comment: You've only half-corrected the classname from SQLServerDriver to Driver. They are both however *still* invalid.

Answer (score 0):

At the first line the "pagkage" have underlined, please let me know to solve it?

package com.stardeveloper.example;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

Comment: Either remove the first line or put the source in a directory tree com/stardeveloper/example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer to this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html

It'll have all the examples you need to connect to MySQL using Connector-J.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("com.MySql.jdbc.Driver");

The "Driver" is it using followinf step to make out?

•Click Control Panel in the Windows OS.
•Click Administrative Tools
•Click Data Sources (ODBC)
•In the form that appears, select Add
•In the next form select the driver from the list – for example SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can try using spring datasource. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/package-summary.html

I have found it convenient. Also, if it's a large scale application consider connection pooling too.