# MySQL and Java driven application

Tags: java, mysql

I am looking to make a Java based application that also uses an external MySQL database. Does anyone know of some good resources that I could read up on? I am very interested to give this a shot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use java to connect to local Mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621785/how-to-use-java-to-connect-to-local-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard API to use databases from Java is JDBC. See the [JDBC Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to learn how to use it.

You'll need a JDBC driver to connect to MySQL. You can get that at the MySQL website: [Connector/J download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a JDBC driver, so you can use pretty much any Java database tutorial to learn how to do it.

You can also use all of the usual candidates for mapping DB resources to Java objects (Hibernate, EclipseLink, ...).